# AVL Tree, delete mininum node (Python 3)

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, tree, avl-tree

I want to implement a huffman coding using AVL tree. I perform some insertion, then I delete some node and everything is fine, but suddenly after another deletion the tree delete every nodes on the right side from root. It happens when the tree looks like this (the right side may be a bit different, but the height is correct):

[image]

after deleting the minim node (M) the tree has only nodes (S, R).
I think that it is because of my mistake in rotation function. Could you help me understand where is the mistake.

```
import random
from collections import Counter


class HuffmanCoding:

def __init__(self, data=None, space=False):
    # Transform data to the form of dictionary
    if data is None:
        data = input("Enter string for coding: ")
        self.data = Counter(data)
    elif isinstance(data, str):
        self.data = Counter(data)
    elif isinstance(data, dict):
        self.data = data
    else:
        raise TypeError("Type of data is incorrect!")

    # Check whether to delete the space or not
    if not space:
        self.data.pop(' ', None)

    self.my_tree = AVL_Tree()
    self.root = None

    for k, v in self.data.items():
        self.root = self.my_tree.insert(self.root, TreeNode(k, v))

def sth(self):
    n1 = self.my_tree.delete_min(self.root)
    n2 = self.my_tree.delete_min(self.root)

    self._create_new_internal_node(n1, n2)

def _create_new_internal_node(self, n1, n2):
    new_node = HuffmanNode(n1, n2)
    self.my_tree.insert(self.root, new_node)


class HuffmanNode:
def __init__(self, n1, n2):
    self.character = n1.character + n2.character
    self.freq = n1.freq + n2.freq
    self.left = None
    self.right = None
    self.height = 1


class TreeNode:
def __init__(self, character, freq):
    self.character = character
    self.freq = freq
    self.left = None
    self.right = None
    self.height = 1


class AVL_Tree:

def insert(self, root, n):
    character = n.character
    freq = n.freq

    # Normal insert, like in BST
    if not root:
        return TreeNode(character, freq)
    elif freq < root.freq:
        root.left = self.insert(root.left, n)
    else:
        root.right = self.insert(root.right, n)

    # Update the height of the ancestor node
    root.height = 1 + max(self.get_height(root.left), self.get_height(root.right))

    # Get the balance
    balance = self.get_balance(root)

    # Left left
    if balance > 1 and freq < root.left.freq:
        return self.right_rotate(root)

    # Right right
    if balance < -1 and freq > root.right.freq:
        return self.left_rotate(root)

    # Left right
    if balance > 1 and freq > root.left.freq:
        root.left = self.left_rotate(root.left)
        return self.right_rotate(root)

    # Right left
    if balance < -1 and freq < root.right.freq:
        root.right = self.right_rotate(root.right)
        return self.left_rotate(root)

    return root

def delete_min(self, root):
    if not root:
        return root

    # Get parent of most left node
    min_parent = self.get_parent_of_min_value_node(root)
    min_node = min_parent.left
    # Check if most left node has a right son
    if min_parent.left.right is not None:
        min_parent.left = min_parent.left.right
    else:
        min_parent.left = None

    # Update the height
    root.height = 1 + max(self.get_height(root.left), self.get_height(root.right))
    balance = self.get_balance(root)

    # Left left
    if balance > 1 and min_parent.freq < root.left.freq:
        self.right_rotate(root)

    # Right right
    if balance < -1 and min_parent.freq > root.right.freq:
        self.left_rotate(root)

    # Left right
    if balance > 1 and min_parent.freq > root.left.freq:
        root.left = self.left_rotate(root.left)
        self.right_rotate(root)

    # Right left
    if balance < -1 and min_parent.freq < root.right.freq:
        root.right = self.right_rotate(root.right)
        self.left_rotate(root)

    return min_node

def get_height(self, root):
    if not root:
        return 0

    return root.height

def get_balance(self, root):
    if not root:
        return 0

    return self.get_height(root.left) - self.get_height(root.right)

def right_rotate(self, z):
    y = z.left
    T3 = y.right

    y.right = z
    z.left = T3

    z.height = 1 + max(self.get_height(z.left), self.get_height(z.right))
    y.height = 1 + max(self.get_height(y.left), self.get_height(y.right))
    return y

def left_rotate(self, z):
    y = z.right
    T2 = y.left

    # Perform rotation
    y.left = z
    z.right = T2

    # Update heights
    z.height = 1 + max(self.get_height(z.left), self.get_height(z.right))
    y.height = 1 + max(self.get_height(y.left), self.get_height(y.right))

    # Return the new root
    return y

def pre_order(self, root):
    if not root:
        return

    print("C: {0}, F: {1}".format(root.character, root.freq))
    self.pre_order(root.left)
    self.pre_order(root.right)

def in_order(self, root):
    if not root:
        return

    self.in_order(root.left)
    print("C: {0}, F: {1}".format(root.character, root.freq))
    self.in_order(root.right)

def post_order(self, root):
    if not root:
        return

    self.post_order(root.left)
    self.post_order(root.right)
    print("C: {0}, F: {1}".format(root.character, root.freq))

def get_min_value_node(self, root):
    if root is None or root.left is None:
        return root

    return self.get_min_value_node(root.left)

def get_parent_of_min_value_node(self, root):
    if root.left is None or root.left.left is None:
        return root

    return self.get_parent_of_min_value_node(root.left)


if __name__ == "__main__":
huffman_coding = HuffmanCoding("Blogoslawieni milosierni")

huffman_coding.my_tree.in_order(huffman_coding.root)


print(huffman_coding.my_tree.delete_min(huffman_coding.root).character)
print(huffman_coding.my_tree.delete_min(huffman_coding.root).character)
print(huffman_coding.my_tree.delete_min(huffman_coding.root).character)
print(huffman_coding.my_tree.delete_min(huffman_coding.root).character)



huffman_coding.my_tree.in_order(huffman_coding.root)

print(huffman_coding.my_tree.delete_min(huffman_coding.root).character)

huffman_coding.my_tree.in_order(huffman_coding.root)

x = huffman_coding.root
```